If the ends of a mile-long bar are pressed $1$ foot closer together, then how high will the midpoint rise?
Years ago, I read an arc-length vs chord length puzzle something like the following:

A bar is $1$ mile in length.  If you press the ends towards each other, allowing the center to rise, how high is the midpoint of the bar when the ends are $1$ foot closer together?

I remember being amazed by the solution (it's several feet), but I don't remember the exact answer, nor do I remember how I calculated it at the time.  Does anyone else remember this problem and how to answer it?
Thanks,
T

In an extreme case where the bar is rigid except its midpoint is like a joint, then the midpoint rises by $\sqrt{(.5~\text{mi})^2-(.5~\text{mi}-.5~\text{ft})^2} > 51~\text{ft}$

If you assume the deformed bar is a circular arc, let $\theta$ be the angle at the center of the circle that the bar subtends, and $r$ be the radius of the circle.  If you draw a straight line between the endpoints you get a chord of the circle with given length $5279$ feet.  If we draw the radius that bisects the chord we get two right triangles.  We have
$$r\theta = 5280\\
2r\sin \left(\frac \theta 2 \right)=5279$$
As $\theta$ is rather small compared to $1$, we can use the first two terms of the Taylor series for the sine
$$2r\left(\frac \theta 2 - \frac 16\left ( \frac \theta 2\right)^3 \right)=5279\\
5280-\frac {r\theta^3}{24}=5279\\
1=\frac {5280}{24}\theta^2\\\theta \approx 0.0674\\r \approx 78300$$
justifying our claim that $\theta \ll 1$  The bulge at the middle is
$$r(1-\cos \frac \theta 2) \approx r \frac {\theta^2} 8\approx 41.9$$
Somewhat less than the straight bar approximation but in the same range.

Interesting to note the final answer is $\approx \sqrt{3M/8}$, where $M=5280$ is the length of the bar. Also, minor point, but I calculate 44.5 for it.

Starting from @Ross Millikan's answer and making the problem more general
$$r\,\theta = a \tag 1$$
$$2r\sin \left(\frac \theta 2 \right)=a-1 \tag 2$$
Using
$$\sin(x) \sim x \,\frac{1-\frac{7 }{60} x^2} {1+\frac{1 }{20} x^2} $$ then
$$\theta \sim \frac{4 \sqrt{15}}{\sqrt{10 a-3}} \quad \text{and} \quad r=  \frac{a \sqrt{10 a-3}}{4 \sqrt{15}}$$
$$r \left(1-\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right) \sim\frac{a \sqrt{10 a-3}}{4 \sqrt{15}} \Bigg(1-\cos \left(\frac{2\sqrt{15}}{\sqrt{10 a-3}}\right)\Bigg)$$
If $a$ is large
$$r \left(1-\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right) \sim\ \sqrt{\frac{3 a}{8} }\,\,\Bigg(1-\frac{7}{20 a}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right) \Big)$$
For $a=5280$ this gives as a result $\frac{105593}{320 \sqrt{55}}=44.4942$.

Here is an approximation based on if you used a mile-long rope instead of a rigid bar:
(The long leg of the right triangle should actually be 2639.5ft).

2639.5$^2$ + $h^2$ = 2640$^2$
$h^2$ = 2640$^2 - 2639.5^2$
$h = \sqrt{2640^2 - 2639.5^2} \approx 51.38$ft
